# Docker-compose multi-network with 1 static ip

Tags: networking, docker, vlan

I have been banging my head with this issue for months now and I just could'n find any example or documentation mentioning this.

Basically I have a docker-compose in which I fire up a bunch of containers and multiple networks.

```
version: "3"

networks:
  vlan65:
    external: true
  traefik_bridge:
  mail_network:
    external: false

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.7-alpine
    container_name: traefik
    restart: ${RESTART_MODE}
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.${MAILSERVER_DOMAIN}
      - traefik.port=8080
      - traefik.docker.network=mail_network
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ${VOLUMES_ROOT_PATH}/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml:ro
      - ${VOLUMES_ROOT_PATH}/traefik/acme:/etc/traefik/acme
    networks:
      vlan65:
        - ipv4_address: 10.0.8.2
      traefik_bridge: null
      mail_network: null
```

vlan65 is declared as external and uses a docker macvlan to allow NATing from the outside into this specific vlan and container.

The problem is that I also need the traefik_bridge and mail_networks available in this container and the IP on the vlan65 should be static (10.0.8.2).

But with this syntax I get the error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.traefik.networks.vlan65 contains an invalid type, it should be an object, or a null
```

Am I missing something obvious or is there a catch in the macvlan implementation?

Comment: With the dash `- ipv4_address: 10.0.8.2` is a one-element list and not an object. This could be what the complaint is about. Try just `ipv4_address: 10.0.8.2`.

Comment: That actually is the solution! If you write an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a YAML syntax error:

With the dash

```
- ipv4_address: 10.0.8.2
```

is a one-element list and not an object. Don't use the dash to get a plain object:

```
    networks:
      vlan65:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.8.2
      traefik_bridge: null
```